# Ты одиозно настроен? Они одиозно настроены?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, заимствования

Какой вопрос не вызывает вопросов, или оба?

Answer (score 2):

*Одиозно* — наречие, образованное от слова *одиозный*, значение которого "вызывающий крайне отрицательное отношение к себе, крайне неприятный" (МАС).

Возникают сомнения, что можно быть *одиозно настроенным* (в Корпусе вообще таких примеров нет). Можно быть *[решительно](http://search2.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%F0%E5%F8%E8%F2%E5%EB%FC%ED%FB%E9&gramm1=&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=%ED%E0%F1%F2%F0%EE%E5%ED%ED%FB%E9&gramm2=&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=), [злобно](http://search2.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%E7%EB%EE%E1%ED%FB%E9&gramm1=&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=%ED%E0%F1%F2%F0%EE%E5%ED%ED%FB%E9&gramm2=&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=), [пессимистично, скептически, агрессивно настроенным](http://search2.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%26&gramm1=(A%7CADV%7CPRAEDIC)&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=%ED%E0%F1%F2%F0%EE%E5%ED%ED%FB%E9&gramm2=&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=&p=0)*, а вот *одиозно*, кажется, нет.

Answer (score -1):

Такие выражения возможны, например:

Ведущий семинара-беседы убедительно просит НЕ приходить выскочек, **одиозно настроенных персонажей** (задача которых, по жизни неуспешных, встревать всюду со своим идиотизмом), анархистов, идеологов и прочий заблудший, злобствующий и беспринципный люд.  http://drugietreningi.ru/events/master/connection.

Одиозно настроенные люди хотят выглядеть  малопривлекательными и вызывать своим поведением раздражение у других людей.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ (одиозность в нашей жизни)**

**ОДИОЗНЫЙ,**  [от лат. odiosus — ненавистный, противный] Книжн. Вызывающий крайне отрицательное отношение к себе, крайне неприятный. **О-ая личность**. Это слово стало одиозным. <Одиозность, -и; ж. О. суждений. О. сюжета.

Некоторые люди очень "одиозно" (= крайне отрицательно) настроены как против наречия "одиозно", так и против людей, употребляющих это слово. В словаре наречие не упоминается, но оно **использовалось и используется** в текстах, авторов которых "безграмотными дислексиками" трудно назвать.

**Согласно словарю, существуют "одиозные личности"** (крайне неприятные, вызывающие раздражение у сограждан). Но те же чувства может вызывать человек, у которого просто плохое настроение и который намеренно раздражает окружающих. **Такое поведение можно назвать одиозным**,  а человека — одиозно настроенным.

**А вообще говоря, люди частенько бывают одиозно настроенными**. Ну всё их раздражает, ко всему они готовы приклеить отрицательный ярлык, унизить и  оскорбить. Одним словом, ведут себя одиозно. А их настроение передается окружающим, что и создает такой замкнутый круг "всеобщей одиозности". Но это уже тема для психологов.

**Примеры из Нацкорпуса (предложения с наречием "одиозно")**

Но в устах Львова все это **звучало совсем не столь одиозно**, сколь в устах советского лидера в атмосфере контрреволюции. [Н. Н. Суханов. Записки о революции / Книга 5 (1918-1921)]

В самодержавной России это привело к тому, что уже в течение трех четвертей века слово «либерал» **звучало неуважительно и одиозно.** [М. В. Вишняк. Два Пути (Февраль и Октябрь) (1931)]

Наверное, **это звучит одиозно**: «…мы не индустриальная (в современном понимании) и тем более не постиндустриальная страна». [А. Ваганов. Нужна ли наука для популяризации науки? // «Наука и жизнь», 2007]

К этому времени уж было забыто, что сей запрет **одиозно противоречит** христианству. [Вадим Деружинский. Когда воскреснем?  (2003) // Интернет-альманах «Лебедь», 2003.08.31]

Отказ от социальных гарантий в сфере труда (или их минимизация) **выглядит еще более одиозно.** [Алия Нуртдинова. // «Отечественные записки», 2003]

Comment: И при этом определении  (малопривлекательный и пр.) можно в лоб человеку задать вопрос типа: ты — злобствующий и беспринципный? Нет, конечно, можно. Но это же будет конец.

Comment: Это может быть примерно  такая ситуация: Ты почему себя так сегодня ведешь? – Как? – Уж очень одиозно настроен. Тогда  это элемент гротеска, чрезмерного увеличения.

Comment: Этот "пример" доказывает только то, что составлять тексты в настоящее время могут и безграмотные дислексики, которых не стоит держать как обоснование: а то я сыпану тинейджерским сленгом из рекламных листовок

Comment: И в примерах из нацкорпуса **нет ни одного** "одиозно настроенного" (против этой пары я и возражаю, не против одиночного наречия или других пар), кроме современной текстовки от *прошаренного поцыка-коуча*